# What do Smiths and Tinkers do?

Tags: heroville

So I recently unlocked the smiths and tinkers in Heroville, what do they do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smiths make weapons. This is everything in the second list of items on the Production tab.

Tinkers make everything else, *except* potions. That is everything but potions in the first list of items on the Production tab.

They will make an item automatically when you do not have full stock. It will take them the same amount of time as clicking to create the item initially, but higher level heroes will work faster. They will make items cheapest first, so a smith will fill the stock of daggers before making any hand axes.